# How trigger MySQL procedure for each row through Laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am making a study project on MySQL. Right now I am trying to accomplish a task using procedures for a table called Books. It is as follows:

```
        CREATE TABLE `books` (
          `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
          `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          `condition` ENUM('mint', 'new', 'medium', 'poor', 'needs replacement'),
          `date_added` DATE 
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

After seeding the table, I have 36 books in it. What I am trying to do, is create a procedure that would amend the `condition` of the book. It shall check the value in this column and if `date_added` column shows that the book has been added >= than one year ago, its condition should be changed to the next ENUM condition. Eg. if the book was added as `mint` one year ago, it's condition should be changed to `new`, if `new` then `medium`, if `medium` then `poor` and so on and so forth.

I've written a bunch of code snippets of which all failed, which pushed me towards realization that apart from synthax issues, I am facing problems with concept understanding, so hope you could help me swipe these misunderstanding away.

The sequence of activities, as I see it:

- create a procedure that's checking and changing the values for a single row;
- create a loop to run the procedure for each table row.

Now, I see that triggers are used with `BEFORE` and `AFTER`, meaning there is no possibility to just trigger the procedure manually. Is this right, or there is a way? I tried to use the loop inside procedure, but got no results. Also, I am continuously getting errors on `condition STRING`, which is no wonder given there isn't suich a type. But, the type I created it with is `ENUM('mint', 'new', 'medium', 'poor', 'needs replacement')`, and I can't use it in type definition. Would appreciate assistance.

The variant I am currently stuck on is as follows:

```
    public function up(): void
    {
        $queryString = /** @lang text */
            "
                CREATE PROCEDURE updateBooksStatus(date DATE, condition ENUM('mint', 'new', 'medium', 'poor', 'needs replacement'))
                BEGIN
                    IF DATEDIFF('2019-08-27', date) >= 365
                        SELECT condition
                        CASE
                            WHEN condition = 'mint' THEN SET 'new'
                            WHEN condition = 'new' THEN SET 'medium'
                            WHEN condition = 'medium' THEN SET 'poor'
                        END
                        FROM `books`;
                    END IF; 
                END
            ";

        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($queryString);
    }
```

Here is DBfiddle with the populated table Books: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28176a/1

Comment: Triggers only fire on insert,update or delete and are not going to be useful to you. I suspect a mysql event would be more appropriate https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html and you need to put a bit more thought into your update logic AND I don't like enums in cases like this.

Comment: I removed the trigger completely as it's not the biggest of issues here, I can run it from console.

Comment: 'if the book was added as mint one year ago' is it possible that  'book was added as medium one year ago' ?

Comment: @P.Salmon As I mentioned, there are 36 books in my table. I am seeding the added_date field with a random date generator, that feeds dates between 2000 and 2019. Also, books were added with different conditions. To bring it to real-world logic, let's consider them a donation from a different library, hence different conditions :)

Comment: If there's only 36 then you could add the table as text or to dbfiddle

Comment: @P.Salmon Added: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28176a/1

Comment: @CheshireKatzzze, just wanted to mention that given the ENUM values are in proper order you can "advance" to the next state by using positions in the ENUM like so: `UPDATE books SET `condition` = LEAST(`condition` + 1, 5) WHERE ...`. Here 5 is ENUM size

Comment: @ragol Thank you, this will help me get rid of the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what should happen if all the dates in sample weren't the same but as commented enums are indexed see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

which means you could do something like this

```
 select id,title,b.condition,b.date_added ,
            date_sub(date(now()),interval 1 year),
            b.`condition` + 0,
            case when date_added =  date_sub(date(now()),interval 1 year) then b.`condition` + 1 end as nxt, 
            b.`condition` + 1 newindex,
            s.condition newcondition
    from books b
    join
    (select distinct `condition`,`condition` + 0 cindex from books) s on s.cindex =     
                case when date_added =  date_sub(date(now()),interval 1 year) then b.`condition` + 1 end ;

+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------+------+----------+-------------------+
| id | title                                                 | condition | date_added | date_sub(date(now()),interval 1 year) | b.`condition` + 0 | nxt  | newindex | newcondition      |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------+------+----------+-------------------+
|  1 | White Fang                                            | mint      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 1 |    2 |        2 | new               |
|  2 | The Call of the Wild                                  | new       | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 2 |    3 |        3 | medium            |
|  3 | Martin Eden                                           | new       | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 2 |    3 |        3 | medium            |
|  4 | The Bishops Apron                                     | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
|  5 | Six Stories Written in the First Person Singular      | new       | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 2 |    3 |        3 | medium            |
|  6 | Judgment Seat                                         | mint      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 1 |    2 |        2 | new               |
|  7 | Princess September and the Nightingale                | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
|  8 | Adventures of Huckleberry Finn                        | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
|  9 | Adventures of Huckleberry Finn                        | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
| 10 | Adventures of Huckleberry Finn                        | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
| 11 | The Prince and the Pauper                             | new       | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 2 |    3 |        3 | medium            |
| 12 | The Aleph and Other Stories                           | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
| 13 | A Universal History of Iniquity                       | new       | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 2 |    3 |        3 | medium            |
| 14 | Dreamtigers                                           | new       | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 2 |    3 |        3 | medium            |
| 15 | Alices Adventures in Wonderland                       | new       | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 2 |    3 |        3 | medium            |
| 16 | Through the Looking-Glass, and What Alice Found There | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
| 17 | The Secret Adversary                                  | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
| 18 | Murder on the Orient Express                          | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
| 20 | The Shining                                           | mint      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 1 |    2 |        2 | new               |
| 21 | The Running Man                                       | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 22 | The Running Man                                       | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 23 | The Running Man                                       | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 24 | The Talisman                                          | mint      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 1 |    2 |        2 | new               |
| 25 | Hamlet                                                | poor      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 4 |    5 |        5 | needs replacement |
| 26 | MacBeth                                               | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 27 | Romeo and Juliet                                      | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 28 | Oliver Twist                                          | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 29 | The Pickwick Papers                                   | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 30 | David Copperfield                                     | mint      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 1 |    2 |        2 | new               |
| 32 | Animal Farm                                           | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 33 | Nineteen Eighty-Four                                  | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 34 | Nineteen Eighty-Four                                  | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 35 | Nineteen Eighty-Four                                  | medium    | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 3 |    4 |        4 | poor              |
| 36 | Burmese Days                                          | mint      | 2018-08-27 | 2018-08-27                            |                 1 |    2 |        2 | new               |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------------------+-------------------+------+----------+-------------------+
```

Presumably if there was a book added as new 5 years ago you would have to add 5 based on date difference?

Comment: OMG, I'll have to investigate your solution as I was moving in a completely different direction. Thank you. As for your question - well, this is not a real case situation, I am just taking random tasks from Google in order to practice.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I have played with this mini-task to grasp what @P.Salmon has shown me, and in the end came with a bunch of very easy approaches to do it, maybe some other newbies will find it useful, posting the shortest and easiest:

```
        $queryString = /** @lang text */
            "
                CREATE PROCEDURE updateBooksStatus()
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE `books` SET `condition` = CASE
                                WHEN `condition` = 'mint' THEN 'new'
                                WHEN `condition` = 'new' THEN 'medium'
                                WHEN `condition` = 'medium' THEN  'poor'
                                WHEN `condition` = 'poor' THEN 'needs_replacement'
                                ELSE
                                `condition`
                            END
                    WHERE `date_added` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
                END
            ";

        DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($queryString);
```